# Entreprise-Application deployed succesfully but it is not running

Tags: wildfly, java-ee-7

I am trying to develop my first web-application based on java-EE. This application should be deployed on WildFly application server. For That purpose, I made my inspiration from https://bitbucket.org/lassitercg/example/src.
I made some modifications on my Code.

I am developing this application using IntelliJ-Community. The Application was successfully deployed.
whenever I try to access the application using the following URL **localhost:8080/startweb**, I get the http status code 404. The code can be found unter this link https://github.com/amitakCsNew/startweb

Since I using Intellij Community edition, I am forced to deploy the application then set the breakpoint in the Controller of the application. The application seems to be succesfully deployed, but I am not jumping to the first breakpoint.

any Idea how I can solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate is needed if you want to deploy and debug directly from the IDE. For the CE you will need to deploy externally and use Remote debug configuration. The common issue is that the app is available under a different context. Check the app server logs for details.

Comment: I deployed externally using the terminal. I started Jboss using standalone.sh. Then I put my war-file on the standalone/deployments-Folder. It worked fine.

Comment: Did you connect with the Remote debug configuration?

Comment: Yes, It is a file called standalone.conf, which is located in /bin. I activated the settings for remote socket debugging.  Then I started the debugger in IntelliJ, after configuring it. I should work, since the deployment was succesful.

Comment: Breakpoint will hit once the code executes in the JVM. Until you find out why the code doesn't run you will not be able to debug it. The issue is not with the IDE.

Comment: I know that the problem is not with the IDE. I dont think, if the backend get requests from browser. I mean that the backend is not reachable from the browser.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webapp layout is wrong. Please refer to the [standard Maven directories layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

You need to move `webapp` directory to `src/main`. Then update `pom.xml` file reference to `web.xml`, then move `META-INF` from `resources` into `webapp` then fix your syntax errors in `index.xhtml` (the same `h` namespace is associated with 2 different URLs), then fix/implement your database, then add faces servlet in `web.xml`, add `faces-config.xml`, then your web app should be available at http://localhost:8080/startweb/.

Once you resolve all the problems and the controller code finally executes, you will be able to debug it from the IDE using Remote debug configuration.

If you are new to all of this, I'd suggest starting with something more simple, like a single JSP page and a single Java servlet.

Post the new questions if you have issues describing what you did to solve the problem and what exactly didn't work. The current question is too broad and your sample project has too many issues to cover in the single answer.

Comment: I fixed the problem by doing these steps:

1- moving webapp-directory to src/main

2- updated pom.xml by referencing web.xml

3- fixing index.xhtml

4- The problem of inserting data into h2-database was solved by renaming the sql-file from insert.sql to import.sql